# Create 2D Array out of another Array which is casted against an API

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, geo

I'm working on a project using the opengeodata and some company-internal APIs. Therefore the code I'm using here is slightly changed.

First I'm using the Opencagedata Javascript API to get the lat/lng-Coordinates out of an address.

```
<script>
function geocode(query) {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
               'key': 'MyKey',
               'q': query,
               'no_annotations': 1
            },
            dataType: 'json',
                statusCode: {
                    200: function(response){  // success
                    var lat = response.results[0]['geometry']['lat'];
                    var lng = response.results[0]['geometry']['lng'];
                    $('#geo_result').text(lat + ' , ' + lng);
```

After that I'm using another internal API to get some information about places surrounding this location. Lets call them POI.

After getting those POIs I'm using splice to filter the three nearest POIs to the lat/lng Coordinates and filter on some specific keywords.

```
var radius = 1.5;
var POI = [];

var apiCall = $.get("CoorpAPI/" + radius + "/around/" + lat + "," + lng);

apiCall.done(function(result) {
                        var myLoc = result.filter(function(loc) {
                            return loc.id.substr(0, 3) != 'keyword';
                        });

$.each(myLoc, function(n, loc) {
                    POI.push(loc.id)
              })

var top3 = POI.slice(0,3);
console.log(top3);
```

Now I want to run those three "top3" POIs ["AB1234", "BC2345", "CD3456"] against a second API which is returns location information.

Those information are supposed to be written into the same array into the second second dimension.

In the end I want to have something Like:

```
[
 0: AB1234
    Location Information: A
    Location Information: B
 1: CD2345
    Location Information: C
    Location Information: D
...
]
```

I guess the loop would have to look somewhat like this, but I'm not sure how to call the API and create a 2d-array out of the "top3" locations and the location information returned by the api:

```
for (var i = 0; i < top3.length; i++) {
    var apiCall_2 = $.get("CoorpAPI_2"+top3[i]);

    // ???
}
```

Comment: There is syntax error in last snippet `})` matches nothing. 2D Array actually doesn't exist in JS but there are nested arrays, So yes, you can store outputs from $.get inside loop in target array so just .append the results to your 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use a nested array inside `POI` to add more information after a second API call. One thing you can try is to `push` an array instead of just `loc.id` in the following manner:

```
POI.push([loc.id]);
```

Now you have a nested array in POI instead of a single string ID (I am guessing the ID is string; can be a number as well). For the second API call you can modify your code like this:

```
var apiCall_2 = $.get('CoorpAPI_2'+top3[i][0]);
```

In this way, you are using the ID which, is the first element in the nested array. Once you process all your data from API call 2, you can either push each data point separately into the nested array or, as another array like this:

```
// pushing each data points separately
top3[i].push(dataPoint1);
// ... up to say N data points
top3[i].push(dataPointN);

// adding as an array
top3[i].push([dataPoint1, dataPoint2, dataPointN]);
```

Your result will be like this:

```
[ ["AB1234", "dataPoint1", "dataPoint2"] ]
```

if you use the first approach and like this

```
[ [ "AB1234", ["dataPoint1", "dataPointN"] ], ]
```

if you use the second approach. Hope this helps.